# Create folders based on filenames

Tags: python, file, iteration, directory, batch-processing

I have a folder with some 1500 excel files . The format of each file is something like this:

- 0d20170101abcd.xlsx
- 1d20170101ef.xlsx
- 0d20170104g.xlsx
- 0d20170109hijkl.xlsx
- 1d20170109mno.xlsx
- 0d20170110pqr.xlsx

The first character of the file name is either '0' or '1' followed by 'd' followed by the date when the file was created followed by customer id(abcd,ef,g,hijkl,mno,pqr).The customer id has no fixed length and it can vary.

I want to create folders for each unique date(folder name should be date) and move the files with the same date into a single folder .
So for the above example , 4 folders (20170101,20170104,20170109,20170110) has to be created with files with same dates copied into their respective folders.

I want to know if there is any way to do this in **python** ? Sorry for not posting any sample code because I have no idea as to how to start.

Comment: Hi. Just to make sure I have understood: the two first digits don't matter. And how should be called the resulting file?

Comment: @LéopoldHoudin the name of the resulting file should be the customer id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this out:

```py
import os
import re

root_path = 'test'


def main():
    # Keep track of directories already created
    created_dirs = []

    # Go through all stuff in the directory
    file_names = os.listdir(root_path)
    for file_name in file_names:
        process_file(file_name, created_dirs)


def process_file(file_name, created_dirs):
    file_path = os.path.join(root_path, file_name)

    # Check if it's not itself a directory - safe guard
    if os.path.isfile(file_path):
        file_date, user_id, file_ext = get_file_info(file_name)

        # Check we could parse the infos of the file
        if file_date is not None \
            and user_id is not None \
            and file_ext is not None:
            # Make sure we haven't already created the directory
            if file_date not in created_dirs:
                create_dir(file_date)
                created_dirs.append(file_date)

            # Move the file and rename it
            os.rename(
                file_path,
                os.path.join(root_path, file_date, '{}.{}'.format(user_id, file_ext)))

            print file_date, user_id


def create_dir(dir_name):
    dir_path = os.path.join(root_path, dir_name)
    if not os.path.exists(dir_path) or not os.path.isdir(dir_path):
        os.mkdir(dir_path)


def get_file_info(file_name):
    match = re.search(r'[01]d(\d{8})([\w+-]+)\.(\w+)', file_name)
    if match:
        return match.group(1), match.group(2), match.group(3)

    return None, None, None


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

---

Note that depending on the names of your files, you might want to change (in the future) the regex I use, i.e. `[01]d(\d{8})([\w+-]+)` (you can play with it and see details about how to read it [here](https://regex101.com/r/Qp9Imt/1))...

Comment: This code kind of works. I am facing with an issue when the customer id consists of a combination of alphabets, numbers and special characters. If the file name is say **'1d2017010123p+abc.xlsx'** where **'123p+abc'** is the customer id , then if I run the code, the folders are created properly but the resultant file name is **'123p'** with an unknown file type. Is there any way to avoid this problem?

Comment: yep, that's normal i'll update my answer. but i'll need you to provide with the least of **all** special characters. or i have an other solution. which one do you prefer: the clean or hardcore?

Comment: Right now the special characters are '-' and '+'. I prefer a solution that's simple and easy to understand :)   is your alternate solution simler than the present one?

Comment: Okay, I updated my answer. Btw is there something you don't understand for the moment? Don't hesitate, I can clarify my answer :)

Comment: The updated code works! I had a problem with file extension but I solved that on my own. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I have one more question. This solution works perfect if I have files of a particular file extension('.xlsx').If I have multiple filetypes like '.csv' ,  '.xls' etc in my root folder how do I move them all into their respective date folder regardless of their file type?

Comment: while keeping their original extension?

Comment: Yes while keeping their original file extension

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180622/discussion-between-leopold-houdin-and-remym).

Answer (score 0):

Check this code.

```
import os

files = list(x for x in os.listdir('.') if x.is_file())

for i in files:
  d = i[2:10] #get data from filename
  n = i[10:] #get new filename
  if os.path.isdir(i[2:10]):
    os.rename(os.getcwd()+i,os.getcwd()+d+"/"+i)
  else:
    os.mkdir(os.getcwd()+i)
    os.rename(os.getcwd()+i,os.getcwd()+d+"/"+i)
```

Here's is the repl [link](https://repl.it/repls/SteelSweetService)

Answer (score 0):

Try this out :

```
import os, shutil
filepath = "your_file_path"
files = list(x for x in os.listdir(filepath) if x.endswith(".xlsx"))
dates = list(set(x[2:10] for x in files))
for j in dates:
    os.makedirs(filepath + j)
for i in files:
    cid = i[10:]
    for j in dates:
        if j in i:
            os.rename(filepath+i,cid)
            shutil.copy2(filepath+cid, filepath+j)
```